# Using tf.boolean_mask with greater_equal to slicing a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use tf.boolean_mask to select certain values from a tensor.

```
myArray = tf.random_normal([6], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
with tf.Session() as test_a:
    myMask =  tf.greater_equal(myArray, 0.5)
    myScores = tf.boolean_mask( myArray, myMask )
    print("myArray = ", myArray.eval())
    print("myMask = ", myMask.eval())
    print("myScores = ", myScores.eval())
```

To which I get the following.

```
myArray =  [-2.24527287  6.93839502  1.26131749 -8.77081585  1.39699364  3.36489725]
myMask =  [False  True  True  True False False]
myScores =  [ 2.71667314  1.12839425  1.47780943  1.50100374]
```

I had expected to get

```
myArray =  [-2.24527287  6.93839502  1.26131749 -8.77081585  1.39699364  3.36489725]
myMask =  [False  True  True  False True True]
myScores =  [ 6.93839502  1.26131749  1.39699364  3.36489725]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Great question! That stumped me for a minute, the answer is ultimately trivial, but an important lesson in how tensorflow operates.

First some working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

myArray = tf.random_normal([6], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
myMask =  tf.greater_equal(myArray, 0.5)
myScores = tf.boolean_mask( myArray, myMask )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([myArray, myMask, myScores]))
```

Result:

```
[array([-2.2452729,  6.938395 ,  1.2613175, -8.770817 ,  1.3969936, 3.3648973], dtype=float32), 
 array([False,       True,       True,       False,      True,      True]), 
 array([6.938395 , 1.2613175, 1.3969936, 3.3648973], dtype=float32)]
```

Notice that myArray is an OP, **not** a variable. An OP (short for operation) is computed at the time that you call `sess.run` (or `eval` in this case, but using `eval` made it less obvious).

A variable, such as `myVar = tf.variable(...)` persists from one call to `sess.run` to another. Since myArray is an OP it was being recomputed each time you performed any operation against the tensorflow graph. Since you called the graph on 3 separate instances you got 3 different values for myArray in each call. You only printed myArray in the first instance of course and erroneously assumed it was remaining static.

Notice with the modified code that I posted I now request all 3 variables in one `sess.run` call, hence they all use the same value of myArray, and all the results are as expected.